# dojo store getIdentity

Tags: dojo

what does store.getIdentity() to exactly:
Lets say I have the following store, what can I do with getIndetity?

```
var store = new dojo.store.Memory({
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: "store1_item1", prime: false},
        {id: 2, name: "store1_item2", prime: true},
        {id: 3, name: "store1_item3", prime: true},
        {id: 4, name: "store1_item4", prime: false},
        {id: "xy", name: "store1_item5", prime: true}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `dojo/store/Memory` source code:

```
// idProperty: String
//     Indicates the property to use as the identity property. The values of this
//     property should be unique.
idProperty: "id",

getIdentity: function(object){
// summary:
//     Returns an object's identity
// object: Object
//     The object to get the identity from
// returns: Number
return object[this.idProperty];
```

i.e.:

```
var id = 1;
store.getIdentity(store.get(id)) == id;
```

You can of course define your own `idProperty`:

```
var store = new dojo.store.Memory({
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: "store1_item1", prime: false},
        {id: 2, name: "store1_item2", prime: true},
        {id: 3, name: "store1_item3", prime: true},
        {id: 4, name: "store1_item4", prime: false},
        {id: "xy", name: "store1_item5", prime: true}
    ],
    idProperty: "name"
});
```

then:

```
var item = store.get("store1_item1"); // item == {id: 1, name: "store1_item1", prime: false}
store.getIdentity(item) == "store1_item1";
```

Basically, it should return a `primary key` of an object retrieved from the store.